# Redirect based on part of filepath to new domain with .htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to work out how my .htaccess should look like to do the following:

Get any url that looks like

> {the protocol}thedomain.co.uk/home/{rest of uri}

OR

> {the protocol}www.thedomain.co.uk/home/{rest of uri}

TO REDIRECT TO

> {the protocol}subdomain.thedomain.co.uk/home/{rest of uri}

Should be pretty simple yet I have the regex skills of a 5 year old. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the .htaccess file of your site's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?thedomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off 
RewriteRule ^(home/.*)$ http%1://subdomain.thedomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just a quick question, how do I make it so that if the url is thedomain.co.uk/home it and not thedomain.co.uk/home/ it gets redirected as well?

Comment: Use `RewriteRule ^(home(/.*)?)$` instead.